# Angular ng-show when active user

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ng-show

I'm tried this tutorial https://github.com/maximepvrt/angular-google-gapi, and I was implementing google login with this plugin, but when I wanna to modification on header.

`Welcome, {{gdata.getUser().name}}! <a ng-click="logout()" ng-show="{{gdata.getUser().name}}" class="uppercase margin-left-10px">logout</a>`

How to change logout to be login when user doesn't active ? Thanks before

Comment: try to change ng-show="gdata.getUser().name"

Comment: @xxlali thanks solved

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<a ng-click="logout()" ng-show="gdata.getUser().name != null && gdata.getUser().name != ''" class="uppercase margin-left-10px">
```

`ng-show` is angular's directive. So you don't need to use {{}} inside this directive.